# Passing php function through ajax to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to create a page that will delete a user from my database when it is searched, ask for confirmation, and then delete it, i am extremely close but i need to pass the function through ajax to java script but im not understanding how to do that. Here is my code:

```
<html> 
<head> 

<?php
    require_once('conn.php');
    function deleteEmployee($conn, $employee, $table){
        $query = "DELETE from $table where EmployeeName = '$employee'";
        $confirmed = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if ($confirmed){
            echo "User Deleted";
        }
        else{      
            return True;
            echo 'User has been deleted';
        }
        return;
    }
    //$query1 = 'select *
?>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var txt;
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
        if (confirm == true) {
            deleteEmployee($conn, $name, "employee");//This is where i am having trouble
        } else {
             txt = "Okay";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form action="" method="post">  
    Search Name to be Deleted: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />  
    <button onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Submit" />submit</button> 
</form>  

<?php
if (!empty($_POST['term'])) {

    $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['term']);     

    $sql = "SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee "; 
    $r_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    if($r_query->num_rows == 0){
         echo "Name not in database";
    } else{
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
            $name = $row['EmployeeName'];  
        } 
    }
}
?>

</form>
```

As of right now, the window pops up but when i press ok, nothing happens since i do not understand how to pass a function through ajax to javascript. Can someone help? If you need more info, let me know

Comment: You won't be able to pass javascript to PHP in that manner. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. You won't need to pass the connection and stuff through the ajax. Just pass the employee name and connect through PHP and delete employee through there

Comment: you can use ajax by get method , so you just do it in ajax page and call that page to this page

Comment: Is it an option to have a .html file and a separate .php file? If so, separete your PHP into a new file and use AJAX to call that file. Alternatively, you won't need to use AJAX and upon confirmation, the page will reload and remove your user. Take your pick and the community may help you further.

Comment: So i put the html in one file, the php in another, and the Ajax and JavaScript in another to make three separate files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), storing your php functions in different files and just past post/get data so your PHP methods can process what you want to process?

Example Usage:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, jQuery wasn't my first option but I can learn it, i just have to read into it

Comment: jQuery just makes things easy with Javascript.